# What are the tiers of angelic and demonic ranking?

Tags: supernatural

There are some clear divisions of power in Supernatural, amongst demons and angels.

Who is at the top of the chain for both? Who are the next few significant ranks?

I know at the top for Angels we have

Lucifer -> Michael and Gabriel....

And demons I *think* we have/had:

Azazel ->Lilith->Crowly?

But I'm not certain.

Comment: What about things that are not angelic or demonic?  There's at least a couple that are up there in the same power range.

Comment: But I'm not interested in raw physical power, Mar their rankings

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is rather crude, a lot of it comes with caveats, I left out a ton of entities and am sure I've forgotten some relationships.  Most of the information is from my own memory and supplemented by the [Supernatural Wikia](http://supernatural.wikia.com/wiki/Supernatural_Wiki).

In general, `Entity 1 → Entity 2` means Entity 1 is more powerful than Entity 2.

Other "relationships", like War being above Pestilence in the image, don't mean anything - that just happens to be where they were placed.

[image: Relationship of entities in Supernatural]

- Death claims to be older than God, and that he will reap God when he dies.  This relationship is uncertain, though, given the sheer age of it.
- Leviathan and Castiel is questionable, since now that they're not organized, Leviathan are, in Crowley's words, just a difficult-to-kill monster, mostly like any other.
- Michael is the one who trapped Lucifer originally, and is the one prophesied to kill Lucifer.
- Castiel and Famine?  Hundreds of hamburgers.
- Alastair once captured several reapers and was prepared to kill them.
- Hellhounds can easily kill demons, but it is unknown how high up the food chain.  The black-eyed demons tend to be the weakest, so that's where I put them.
- I've put the Mother of All above Castiel, since we know she's older than angels, and can block their powers.  However, I don't recall her interacting with the Archangels, so they may or may not be immune to that ability.
- *Update 2014-01-09:*  This was a long time coming (like, the entire past season), but I forgot about this question/answer - now that we've finally met Metatron, we know his strength/power level is actually much lower than other angels.  He supplements that with immense knowledge due to having written the Word of God tablets, but he needed Castiel to actually *do* anything.

---

<sub>For the sake of allowing anyone to be able to edit the image, I generated it using [Graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/), with [this dot file](http://pastebin.com/PUmmzNKR).</sub>

Comment: Ugh. No. Death is a being on par with God, but the other 3 "horsemen" are just demons. It should not be forgotten that a nearly powerless Castiel manages to overpower Pestilence (briefly). Also, Gabriel is clearly weaker than Lucifer, not to mention younger. Eve was a leviathan, though possibly one of the weaker ones. Reapers are, I think, Death's version of Angels. Finally, even weaker beings can manage to overpower more powerful beings with magic and surprise.

Comment: @JohnO No, the other 3 horsemen aren't demons.  They're embodiments of concepts, and can't be killed, just de-powered for a time.  I had forgotten about Castiel and Pestilence, though.

Comment: @JohnO Eve was most definitely not a Leviathan.  She was independent (did not follow Dick), had tons of powers Leviathan do not have, and weaknesses they did not have (Phoenix ash).

Comment: Sorry, but we already saw this with the "Seven Deadly Sins". Plain demons.

Comment: @JohnO I agree with your point about Reapers, but attaching them in graphviz made a huge mess; I figured the extended relationship was good enough.  And lastly, the question is about their "starting point" for lack of a better word.  Extra magic and surprise not counted.

Comment: @JohnO Yes, the Seven Deadly Sins were demons that came into existence around the Medieval times.  They are completely unrelated to the Four Horsemen of the Apocalypse.

Comment: It's already been settled. The alpha vampire confirmed it here recently. He said "you and I we're related", and Edgar replied "just barely" and "Eve was a whore"... confirming that she was a leviathan. Though likely one of the weakest, if not in raw power then certainly by the leviathans way of thinking.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/4264/discussion-between-john-o-and-izkata)

Answer (score 4):

Supernatural is just like any other television show with a vast cast and varying levels of superhuman ability. Likely no one sits down and creates a major graph of how is the most powerful and new characters appear whose powers challenge the previous top dogs who, at the  time were considered the most powerful forces in the series. So is there a real potential to determine who is the most powerful, or is this mostly a fan exercise that the writers of the series barely pay attention to because they have to create a series every week and just don't have time.

All things considered, Supernatural does a fairly good job of remembering who is on top and why.

- **God, Yahweh** is on top, though we have never seen him/her (that we know of) we know the Universe came to be and the Angels are the unhappy caretakers of what's left since he/she has disappeared.
- **Archangel Michael** has proven to be the next largest dog on the porch and the only person who has the raw power and ability  to handle Lucifer, the First Fallen Archangel and de facto ruler of Hell, even if he rules in absentia.
- **The other Archangels** are the Powers who rule Heaven in God's place. They are fractious, unhappy and wonder what happened to make God forsake them. A few even try to engineer the Apocalypse in order to reset the Earth and maybe drive God out of hiding; it doesn't work.
- A strange outlier is **Death**. He claims to be outside of the power structure that Angels and Demons participate in. He claims that he will one day reap God, but I took that statement to be hyperbole since he is a part of the Universe, he had to have come into existence when God did. So I don't believe he would be able to "reap" God, but certainly the two of them will leave the Universe when that time comes together. Everything else, in the Universe, may be fair game to him, making him a scary force that everyone makes an effort to avoid. The Horsemen of the Apocalypse on the other hand appear to be cannon fodder recruited from human lives and given powers to help them promote their office.
- **Other Angels:** Now it gets murky. Religious texts indicate there are three tiers of angels but we don't ever hear the angels really talk about this, so besides the Archangels we are forced to assume the difference is mostly cosmetic from the scale of the humans who see them. First Sphere and Second Sphere Angels are mentioned in the Bible, visit humans, deliver catastrophes and divine edicts.  I start at the third tier of power with this being the level of Angels we see all the time. Third Tier angels are powerful and most other beings fear them. Even powerful monsters and named Demons avoid the attention of even Third Tier Angels.
- **Third Tier Angels:** Even with their power level, we see Third Tier Angels get wacked by other Angels, demons and even humans armed with Angel Killing Swords. They can be killed by surprise, they can be sent back to Heaven with Enochian symbols and this means their superhuman abilities are not perfect.
- **The Reapers** populate a tier of power between Demons and Other soul harvesting artifacts. They seem to function like Angels but work exclusively for Death. This might also be the same tier of power the Horsemen of the Apocalypse seem to function at. Deriving some of their power from Death, the Horsemen seem to have a power level equal to that of Named Demons.
- Below them would be creatures like the **Purgatory Monsters** who had an entire reality created to keep them away from everything else in our universe. These include creatures like the Leviathans and Eve. These creatures are powerful enough that even named Demons, Leader Demons, and Leader Monsters are not happy to see them and do everything in their power to make them go away. A single Leviathan has proven to be a match for any demon, any third tier Angel and any monster walking the planet, hence the reason for their imprisonment.
- **Specials and Uniques:** Individual artifacts, weapons, weaponized people and unique monsters populate this tier. This includes the Eve, the Antichrist, the Special Children, of which Sam was a member, The Colt, and the Scythe of Death. Looking at the Scythe and Colt, if used by the right hands or with the right knowledge claim to be able to kill almost anything.
- **Demons and Monsters** populate the lowest tier of monsterdom in the Supernatural Universe. These are the creatures that Hunters cut their teeth on and if they survive eventually draw the attention of the Demon Leaders and Monster Leaders, the creatures of legend.

At the bottom of this list is the lowly Human, food source for most monsters, but blessed with the benefit of a soul for which most monster seek for nourishment, fuel, money, or magical power. Despite their food status, humans when properly trained and equipped with sufficient knowledge can be a formidable foe, capable of holding its own against all but the most powerful of these creatures. No individual human is particularly powerful, but they can learn magic, bind and hold demons, destroy and kill most monsters and using the right technology hold most non-angelic creatures at bay.

This is an imperfect list, just like Supernatural is an imperfect show. For the most part they do a pretty good job of keeping their power structure intact.

[image: Whose on Top?]

*Open image in a new tab to see at full size.*

Answer (score 1):

> !Among the angels, Michael is *clearly* the most powerful. This can be seen in the final showdown between him and Lucifer. Lucifer acknowledges that it is, at best, a longshot that he should triumph, but feels compelled to fight anyway. In earlier episodes though, to other people/angels, Lucifer would be full of bravado, probably an attempt to convince himself that he could win.
>
> !Second to him though he might be, Lucifer is an incredible power that lays waste to many beings considered deities. And not one-on-one either, they pile on to him... and he just smites them. Furthermore, while Lucifer is clearly no match for Death (Incarnate), he does manage to trick Death with magic that enslaves him. Whether this should be considered impressive or not I leave to you the reader, after all, a junkyard owner manages to accomplish the same thing later in the series.
>
> !Next in line would be two more angels, Raphael and Gabriel. We are never given any clues as to which is stronger than the other. But both are archangels proper, and in theory capable of killing Lucifer and/or Michael (something no ordinary angel could ever manage). It seems likely that they might manage this without their angelic blades (swords of archangels, and all that), but they are armed with the means to do so at the very least.
>
> !Next in line I would put post-resurrection (second time) Castiel. He was somewhat lowly originally, but he is quite clearly capable of resurrecting the dead after the end of season 5. While Raphael was probably still capable of smiting him, I suspect that it might have been just a bit more difficult than it would with any other angel.
>
> !Now, compared to demons... even the lowliest angel seems both capable of smiting them and invulnerable. Alistair (a powerful demon as far as they go) laments that he cannot kill them, only send them back to Heaven temporarily.
>
> !Crowley seems much more powerful in seasons 6 and 7, but it is revealed that he has the help of Castiel to some degree or another, and can marshal the forces of Hell in their entirety.
>
> !I suspect that Ruby, Lilith, and Azazel were never as powerful as Crowley is in later seasons. They knew esoteric magic and might be able to interfere with powers greater than themselves (for a few moments anyway), but they are all dead and Crowley remains.
>
> !Meg is savvy, but does not seem particularly adept at the black magic that might make her more powerful. If you ask Crowley for the spell to bind Death, 24 hours later you have a parchment in your hands. But Meg has only ever used blood to communicate with other demons.
>
> !No other still-living (wrong word? still-existing?) demons are even named.
>
> !It's unclear where the Hell-forged knife comes from. Demons may have constructed it, or merely came into possession of it at some point in the past.

Comment: +1 one for a great break down of raw-power, but I meant more like the hierarchy of power originally. This is why I put Lucifer on top, as he was created first, in-universe, correct? Spoilers are made by starting the line with >!

Comment: No. If you mean was he born first, Michael refers to him as "little brother". If you mean he showed up first episode-wise, Michael was mentioned early on as well (though, without a willing vessel couldn't make an onscreen appearance). The hierarchy is quite clear at first (Michael, Lucifer, Gabriel/Raphael), but becomes muddied quickly. Demons are *always* at the bottom.

Comment: @Pureferret The Supernatural Wiki has lists of the types of [angels](http://supernatural.wikia.com/wiki/Angels#Types_of_Angels) and [demons](http://supernatural.wikia.com/wiki/Demons#Types_of_Demons), which may help in ordering the angels and demons that have appeared in episodes in terms of power.

Comment: There are however some characters that don't quite fall in place nicely. Castiel fits in at different levels as the seasons progress; at the height of his power (end of season six/beginning of season seven) he's more powerful than at least one Archangel. There's also the anti-Christ (from season six, I believe?), who is part demon and seemingly more powerful than an angel.

Comment: Well, we never do learn if leviathans are more powerful than archangels or merely only more powerful than plain angels. If Lucifer weren't stuck in the Cage, we might have seen him kick their asses just like he did with Odin and Ganesh. I wouldn't even know where to begin to fit the Antichrist into all of that.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist Season five. I'm mostly interested in  what their power was *off the starting blocks* so to speak.

Comment: Michael, Lucifer, Gabriel/Raphael, all other angels. In that order.

Comment: @JohnO You forgot about Metatron.  He has yet to appear, but has been mentioned by Castiel.

Comment: @izkata, isn't he a transformer?

Comment: @Pureferret [Just like Sam and Dean](http://www.tvfanatic.com/quotes/this-is-the-handwriting-of-metatron-metatron-youre-saying-a/), no.  That's Megatron.

Answer (score 0):

I think this power chart but have a few alterations. Michael WAS stronger than lucifer initially but this could have easily been a shock to an unprepared lucifer"why brother why I don't wanna right" a sentiment he later expresses at the end. Also lucifer could have gained power being in hell. Angela and I assume archangels get their juice from heaven and the collective souls there. Maybe archs have their own battery thru a connection to God, and heaven may have a resovoir of power aside from souls after all that's a lotta angels and a finite number of souls in heaven. Meanwhile lucifer was the only angel in hell, even if demons don't provide as much juice as untainted souls he had the whole thing to himself. Keep in mind he needed a powerful psychic drinking demon blood to strengthen himself in vessel form without deteriorating, nick only drank demon blood he wasn't a psykid. I think lucifer was atleast on even terms and possibly stronger than Michael at the end. As for Crowley being stronger than the white eyed demons and azazel i call bullshit. In his season 6 he mentioned his position wasn't stable and even as the strongest crossroads demon he was still a red eye, albeit with red smoke form. I assume he elevated to the rank of say alastair, maybe even Azazel who was described as the tyrant ruler of demons (king of hell at time) lillith may have been stronger it's up to debate i still think yellow eyes signify fallen angel status, think Anna or castiel. What If they died as evil humans. Azazel was the only demon to ever be immune to salt and holy water, a possible carryover from his non human origin? Iron couldn't be crossed and devils traps may have worked but who knows, and  simon minor angel mojo plus millennia of hell cloud churn out a powerful demon. Samhain I assume is just under Alastair in power. Id reckokn samhainn could throw down with a  mook angel if not the likes of uriel or castiel, that is unless his lirtkw reicks let him use ghosts and or zombies as distractions while he used a chant like alastaie did to send em back upstairs assuming he knows the spell. And as for castiel i think he got two power boosts, one as a reward for helping Sam

And dean, And then another once Crowley gave him 50,000 souls from hell. I believe he was as strong or probably stronger than Zachariah , meaning a weaker arch like raph couldn't smite him like before hence him frying the angel sword. Purgatory cas aka godstiel was A full order stronger than an archangel atleast to raphael, and seemed fo think he could kill Death. Maybe not but he'd probably be able to bind him on his own atleast if not hurt him somehow. I also like to believe that the other 3 horsemen were human once, maybe being quasi demons imbued with some of Death's essence, tied to their ring and taking on the personification. I think an archangel or maybe godstiel if he hasn't ingested them, could have killed or atleast disentegrated some leviathans. Maybe only dick being immune but he not having the power to do much against them itd
Be a stalemate, unless  they could just toss him on the moon or maybe back to purgatory for that matter.

Comment: Please consider editing this for formatting and to make it more concise.

Answer (score -1):

Well heres the list

1- GOD - obviously because he is the one above all and nothing can harm him. Every other character in supernatural - even death is nothing more than god's little bitch. Death says he will reap god in the end but wait...poor death can't reap the god who is truly immortal- infact god has no beginning no end while death was just god's creation. Plus every event in supernatural is nothing but god's will so yeah the greatest of all - GOD bags the number 1 :D

2- THE WINCHESTERS
okay this might be contradictory and debatable as in terms of strength,intelligence and other abilites...the archangels and demons and other monsters easily beat the winchesters but there is something about the winchesters coz of which they have defeated every single creature they have faced so far- they died and still came back again and again...from both heaven and hell and no creature has truly been able to stop them- not even death. Maybe its because GOD is with the winchesters and so nothing can harm the winchesters truly!

3- DEATH - the strongest of the four horsemen...death is powerful than every creature ever appeared in the series (excluding god). Despite claiming to be able to reap god...he has to follow a "natural order" of killing people written by god himself. Despite of what he says...he is at the end of the day just another one of god's little bitch. Simply putting..god is as beyond death as death is beyond everyone else

4- THE ARCHANGELS 
Michael being strongest - king of heaven and the only known entity after god and death who can kill lucifer
Then lucifer - king of hell and the devil !
then Gabriel and Raphael - though both can kill lucifer but lucifer is much smarter.

5- LEVIATHANS

6- MOTHER OF ALL MONSTERS - EVE

7- Super Castiel

8- AZAZEL or LILITH
being among the strongest demons or probably the strongest ones maybe. I think lilith is stronger than azazel as lilith was the first demon and the oldest and probably the smartest and strongest. And azazel was killed by colt. 
Plus sam was able to kill lilith so his powers could kill azazel too...though he would need alot of juice!

9- Jesse the demon human kid or maybe that nephilim girl

10- CROWLEY or SAMHEIN !

Answer (score -1):

Strongest of anything would be GOD the creater. 
This would be angels list of power which id say no demon would really be more powerful then.
1st would be the arch angels listed in order of power. 1 Michael 2 Lucifer 3 Gabriel 4 Raphael.
2nd would be angels in the garacien such as castile, mirial, Anna and any others not really knowing who's stronger they are all soldiers trained to fight. Also up here I would say angels such as Zachariah and Joshua. I would put metatron up her to even though they call him an arch angel he says it himself he is just a paper pusher and a secretary of god but as seen he is powerful this is debatable.
3rd would be the work the worker angels like cupid when he was on the show it was said he is in the 3rd tier of angels and carries out heavens orders and any other angels that carry out orders like that would be their.

Demons
as it goes on demons die and others become more powerful because they rule certain things gaining more souls and followers it is a trickiy list.
Top demons are all those with eyes other then just being black.
azaizel, Lilith, alister, Crowley, abadon, and I would put sam hain up here to but he has been locked away and never really gets to show his real powers.
the next demons are the important one such as meg, ruby. ones that help with the plan to free Lucifer or follow him to protect.
then its your everyday black eyed demons just low level there to carry out orders and the everyday demons sam and dean kill almost on a daily basis.
The demon kid would be at the top but he yet doesn't use his powers for bad and disappeared. but he is human to so can easily be killed. making him not the strongest thing. And the horsemen ARE ON here the might be powerful and seen pestilence is stronger then castile but that is only with the ring on the can all be shut down except death he is not on this part of the list. also they don't even hurt the normal demon don't know why though.

Now comes death he said he can reap god when its his time to die or if he is killed if possible. he can kill anything with his touch or his weapons. his reaper are strong but they work by the book unless bound by a human or creater. now on this to I would put faith the sisters on here as she shows her power of the youngest sister and desides how you will die.

Monsters 
I put eve first as she shows she created every monster except the leviathan and can shut off angel powers. She also can only be killed by pheniox ass hince prolly why the are hard to find when she rises from purgatory. she can also create new monster how ever she wants and she is so strong she make all monster here her and they will start killing even if good monsters and can see and hear everything they do.
now as leviathan go they are strong and hard to kill have the power to change into other people and eat anything. why god put them in purgatory they would of ate the universe. 
now come the alphas being they created the monsters of there kind and as seen the can tak a lot more damge and more strength then the daily monster.
last is you everyday daily monster just the norm dangours but can be killed.

Ghost 
there are not to many types of ghost but I would put a poltergeist at the top the just your vengeful spirit and ones that take other spirits energy.

Witches

they get there own category as they are human and still go to heaven or hell I take all go to hell from the show but then again there are good witches that don't hurt know one but I think all witches have to sell there soul to demons can live forever but when they die the demons claim the soul. they have very much power all at different levels such as age and what some specialize in and there lifestyle

Human hunters

It is known Dean is probably the best hunter with his mentality. Sam isn't much behind though if not at all when he has his powers he is stronger then any hunter or demon and can take on horseman so he is very powerful. with no soul he is a good as hunter but no care for human life.
Booby has his knowledge making him a great asset
Ruffice 
ellen
joe
garth 
ash also with his Intel and technology and Fank 
and any other hunter they may run into.

Comment: oh and when castile becomes god he is probably the most powerful bean but can still be killed and stopped by death and his vessel is not strong enough for the souls